# How to integrate Easy Auth with .NET Core 3.1 MVC App?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, easy-auth

I am developing a .NET Core 3.1 MVC App and then publishing it to Azure Web App. In the Azure portal, for this hosted app -> I enabled App Service Authentication with AzureAD Login. But then the authentication doesn't work as "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is always coming as false in the Controller and I can't fetch other user details I want to, like email etc. Upon searching I found there is a workaround using a Nuget Package for >Net Core 2.2 (https://github.com/MaximRouiller/MaximeRouiller.Azure.AppService.EasyAuth), but I don't see any solution for 3.1.

However, when I setup custom auth by disabling the App Service Authentication in Azure, and set the auth in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

and this:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => ...
```

with config in appsettings.json, the auth works fine and I can fetch user details as well.

But our preferred solution is not to have any auth settings/custom auth in code and rather handle it fully on the portal using Azure AD Easy Auth with .NET Core 3.1 MVC app. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Does your workaround definitely lead to a secure app? How does this approach working during local development? Can you debug locally, or are you restricted to publishing to Azure every time you want to test a change?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation for EasyAuth and .NET Core as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims). The User Principal is implemented differently in .NET Core and EasyAuth can't grab those details *automagically* like it can in .NETFX. That is why you need to use Maxime's workaround.